# Keep track of variables in Higher order functions

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

Can anybody please explain how variable value can exist after finish running the function?
I saw a code example of Higher order function but I don't understand how it keep track of variable in function after each run of the function.
in example below how variable count can add more after each run?

```js
// Higher order functions

// A higher order function is any function that does at least one of the following
//   1. Accepts a function as an argument
//   2. Returns a new function

// Receives a function as an argument
const withCount = fn => {
  let count = 0

  // Returns a new function
  return (...args) => {
    console.log(`Call counts: ${++count}`)
    return fn(...args)
  }
}

const add = (x, y) => x + y

const countedAdd = withCount(add)

console.log(countedAdd(1, 2))
console.log(countedAdd(2, 2))
console.log(countedAdd(3, 2))
```

Comment: Short answer is that `countAdd` is the anonymous function returned from `withCount()` and `count` is clearly in scope inside `withCount` and therefore inside the anonymous function also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the withCount function is called only once:

```
const countedAdd = withCount(add)
```

After that call, the variable `count` is created, and because they still have possible references in the same scope as it exists, it is not destroyed, making possible the use inside the scope.

Please note that the arrow function returned is inside the scope(function withCount).

Answer (score 1):

*What if*¹ there would be no variables at all? *What if* there would only be a tree of, lets say objects? Each object has a list of key-value pairs, and a reference to its parent. Now how could we emulate variables with that tree? Well for global variables that is easy, we have to have some reference to the "global scope object" somehow, then we can add a key-value pair to that:

```
 // var test = "value";
 global.test = "value";
```

Now how do we represent a local scope? Quite easy: whenever a function gets called, we create a new such object, and let the parent reference point to the root object.

```
 local.parent -> global
 local.count = 0;
```

Now from that local function scope we can both look up local variables (`count` for example) and global ones, simply by traversing to the parent of the current scope and checking the variable there (`test` for example).

And for a function inside a function? Thats easy too: We just let the parent of the current scope object point to the one of the outer function:

```
 local2.parent -> local
```

Now to look up `count` in that inner scope, we can go to the `parent` and find it as a property there.

Now the trick is, that those "context objects" do not disappear when the function ends execution, but rather when all references to it were lost.

Now we need another trick to make your example work:
A *function declaration* has to keep a reference to its parent scope, so when the function gets called, we can let the local scopes `parent` point to the parent scope.

Therefore if you do `return (...args) => {`, a reference will be kept to the "current scope object" (which contains `count`) and will be stored on the function. When you call it, the function will be executed with a new scope object, and that can access `count` through the parent reference. As long as you keep a reference to that function, the internal reference to that "scope object" will be kept, and that contains `count`.

---

¹ actually, this is exactly what happens. The ECMA spec calls these "scope objects" *EnvironmentRecord* ...

Answer (score 0):

The thing you see here is called closure. You can find many good articles, books, explaining this concept. Basically, it's keeping an implicit reference to a variable.

```
The returned function below closes over variable `count`
return (...args) => ...
```

So when you call `withCount`, you retain a secret reference to `count`. And the other functions you called, just keep interacting with that variable.